# Command event not firing when bound to an event in a custom control

Tags: asp.net, events, authentication, command, controls

I have a custom control that I am writing to display a login form. The "Login" button should perform a different action based on the page it's implemented in. So, in the page codebehind, I am trying to set the Command event of the Login Button contained in the control to fire a method that is defined in the page codebehind. The form and everything renders fine, but the event is not firing when the Login button is clicked.

Any ideas on why the Command event is not firing would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Control Code "LoginForm.cs"

```
public enum LoginFormType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Standard.
    /// </summary>
    [Description("Standard")]
    Standard = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// Customer Manager.
    /// </summary>
    [Description("Customer Manager")]
    CustomerManager = 1,
}

public class LoginForm : Panel
{
    public bool ShowInstructions = true;
    public bool ShowForgotPassword = true;
    public bool ShowRegisterLink = false;
    public LoginFormType FormType = LoginFormType.Standard;

    // inputs
    public TextBox UsernameBox = new TextBox();
    public TextBox PasswordBox = new TextBox();

    // buttons
    public Button LoginButton = new Button();
    public Button ForgotPasswordButton = new Button();

    // wrappers (<p> tags)
    private HtmlGenericControl _InstructionsWrapper = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
    private HtmlGenericControl _UsernameLabelWrapper = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
    private HtmlGenericControl _UsernameBoxWrapper = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
    private HtmlGenericControl _PasswordLabelWrapper = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
    private HtmlGenericControl _PasswordBoxWrapper = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
    private HtmlGenericControl _ButtonsWrapper = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
    private HtmlGenericControl _RegisterWrapper = new HtmlGenericControl("p");

    // literals (text)
    private Literal _Instructions = new Literal();
    private Literal _UsernameLabel = new Literal();
    private Literal _PasswordLabel = new Literal();
    private Literal _Register = new Literal();
    private Literal _Spacer = new Literal();

    // panels
    private Panel _Errors = new Panel();

    public LoginForm()
    {
        // IDs of dynamically added controls need to be declared here for scope
        this._InstructionsWrapper.ID = "LoginFormInstructionsWrapper";
        this._UsernameLabelWrapper.ID = "LoginFormUsernameLabelWrapper";
        this._UsernameBoxWrapper.ID = "LoginFormUsernameBoxWrapper";
        this._PasswordLabelWrapper.ID = "LoginFormPasswordLabelWrapper";
        this._PasswordBoxWrapper.ID = "LoginFormPasswordBoxWrapper";
        this._ButtonsWrapper.ID = "LoginFormButtonsWrapper";
        this._RegisterWrapper.ID = "LoginFormRegisterLinkWrapper";
        this.UsernameBox.ID = "LoginFormUsernameBox";
        this.PasswordBox.ID = "LoginFormPasswordBox";
        this.LoginButton.ID = "LoginFormLoginButton";
        this.ForgotPasswordButton.ID = "LoginFormForgotPasswordButton";
    }

    public void DisplayError(string errorMessage)
    {
        Literal message = new Literal();
        message.Text = errorMessage;

        this._Errors.Controls.Add(message);
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        // element spacer
        this._Spacer.Text = "&nbsp;";

        // instructions
        if (this.ShowInstructions)
        {
            this._Instructions.Text = LoginFormResources.Instructions;
            this._InstructionsWrapper.Controls.Add(this._Instructions);
            this.Controls.Add(this._InstructionsWrapper);
        }

        // username label
        this._UsernameLabel.Text = LoginFormResources.Username;
        this._UsernameLabelWrapper.Controls.Add(this._UsernameLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this._UsernameLabelWrapper);

        // username box
        this._UsernameBoxWrapper.Controls.Add(this.UsernameBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this._UsernameBoxWrapper);

        // password label
        this._PasswordLabel.Text = LoginFormResources.Password;
        this._PasswordLabelWrapper.Controls.Add(this._PasswordLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this._PasswordLabelWrapper);

        // password box
        this.PasswordBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
        this._PasswordBoxWrapper.Controls.Add(this.PasswordBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this._PasswordBoxWrapper);

        // buttons
        this.LoginButton.Text = LoginFormResources.Login;
        this._ButtonsWrapper.Controls.Add(this.LoginButton);

        if (this.ShowForgotPassword)
        {
            this._ButtonsWrapper.Controls.Add(this._Spacer);
            this.ForgotPasswordButton.Text = LoginFormResources.ForgotPassword;
            this._ButtonsWrapper.Controls.Add(this.ForgotPasswordButton);
        }

        this.Controls.Add(this._ButtonsWrapper);

        // errors panel placeholder
        this.Controls.Add(this._Errors);

        // register link
        if (this.ShowRegisterLink && this.FormType != LoginFormType.CustomerManager)
        {
            this._Register.Text = String.Format(LoginFormResources.Register, "<a href=\"register.aspx\">", "</a>");
            this.Controls.Add(this._Register);
        }

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

Page Codebehind "Default.cs"

```
public class Default : CustomerManagerPage
{
    public Content BreadcrumbContent = new Content();
    public Content PageContent = new Content();

    public Label Breadcrumb = new Label();

    public LoginForm LoginFormControl = new LoginForm();

    public Panel ForgotPasswordModal = new Panel();
    public ModalPopupExtender ForgotPasswordMPE = new ModalPopupExtender();

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
    }


    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LoginFormControl.FormType = LoginFormType.CustomerManager;
        LoginFormControl.ShowInstructions = true;
        LoginFormControl.ShowRegisterLink = true;
        LoginFormControl.LoginButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this._LoginButton_Command);


        _BuildForgotPasswordModal();


        if (IsPostBack)
        { }
    }

    private void _LoginButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("FIRED");
        /*
        try
        {
            Library.Login.AuthenticateUser(LoginFormControl.UsernameBox.Text, LoginFormControl.PasswordBox.Text);

            Response.Redirect("/");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoginFormControl.DisplayError(ex.Message);
        }
        */
    }

    private void _BuildForgotPasswordModal()
    {
        this.ForgotPasswordMPE.ID = "ForgotPasswordMPE";

        // header
        Panel header = new Panel();
        Label headerTitle = new Label();

        headerTitle.ID = "ModalHeaderTitle";
        headerTitle.Text = "Confirm";


        header.ID = "ModalHeader";
        header.CssClass = "ModalHeader";

        header.Controls.Add(headerTitle);

        // body
        Label forgotPasswordText = new Label();
        TextBox usernameBox = new TextBox();
        Button forgotPasswordSubmitButton = new Button();
        Button cancelButton = new Button();
        Panel body = new Panel();
        Panel hr = new Panel();

        forgotPasswordText.ID = "ForgotPasswordText";
        forgotPasswordText.Text = "<p>Enter your username in the box below, then click 'Submit'.</p> <p>Your password will be reset and emailed to the email address associated with your account.</p>";

        usernameBox.ID = "ForgotPasswordUsername";

        forgotPasswordSubmitButton.ID = "ForgotPasswordSubmit";
        forgotPasswordSubmitButton.Text = "Submit";

        cancelButton.ID = "ForgotPasswordCancel";
        cancelButton.Text = "Cancel";
        cancelButton.OnClientClick = "javascript:$find('" + ForgotPasswordMPE.ClientID + "').hide(); return false;";

        hr.ID = "ModalHr";
        hr.CssClass = "ModalHr";

        body.ID = "ModalBody";
        body.CssClass = "ModalBody";

        body.Controls.Add(forgotPasswordText);
        body.Controls.Add(usernameBox);
        body.Controls.Add(hr);
        body.Controls.Add(forgotPasswordSubmitButton);
        body.Controls.Add(cancelButton);

        // modal
        this.ForgotPasswordModal.Controls.Add(header);
        this.ForgotPasswordModal.Controls.Add(body);

        // modal properties
        this.ForgotPasswordModal.ID = "ForgotPasswordModal";
        this.ForgotPasswordModal.CssClass = "ModalContainer";

        // modal popup extender
        this.ForgotPasswordMPE.TargetControlID = this.LoginFormControl.ForgotPasswordButton.ClientID;
        this.ForgotPasswordMPE.PopupControlID = this.ForgotPasswordModal.ID;
        this.ForgotPasswordMPE.OkControlID = forgotPasswordSubmitButton.ID;
        this.ForgotPasswordMPE.CancelControlID = cancelButton.ID;
        this.ForgotPasswordMPE.BackgroundCssClass = "ModalBackground";
    }
}
```

"Default.aspx"

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyApplication.CustomerManager.Pages.Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BreadcrumbContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="BreadcrumbContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Breadcrumb" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="asm" runat="server" EnableScriptLocalization="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" />
    <ctrls:LoginForm ID="LoginFormControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Panel ID="ForgotPasswordModal" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    <atk:ModalPopupExtender ID="ForgotPasswordMPE" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

**UPDATE: THE ISSUE IS RESOLVED!**

The answer was not quite life cycle, but sort of had to do with life cycle.

First, having the control inherit from Panel (as a lazy way to render it in a div) is not right. I changed it to inherit WebControl and added : base(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div) to the constructor so that it renders in a div. This was the minor part of the fix.

The actual fix for this issue was to have the control also inherit INamingContainer. This was the most important part and is apparently necessary for the controls children to raise postback events.

The first portion of this fix was only necessary because even after inheriting INamingContainer, it still didn't work. But after changing it to inherit both WebControl, and INamingContainer, it worked. Still not quite sure why I couldn't inherit Panel, and INamingContainer, but at this point I'm not sure I care enough to research it.

Comment: why i cant find loginButton in Default.aspx

Comment: LoginButton is contained entirely in the control code... The control itself is a single entity instansiated in the Default page. "<ctrls:LoginForm ID="LoginFormControl" runat="server" />" in the aspx, and public LoginForm LoginFormControl = new LoginForm(); in the codebehind of the Default page.

Comment: More information... Ignore the call to base.CreateChildControls(); in the OnPreRender override in the control code, that was left over from me playing with different methods to override when i was (and i still kind of am) under the assumption that the issue has to do with page lifecycle.

Comment: Even more information :)... Just to give a bit of understanding on how my application is structured as a whole, as I am fully aware that there are simpler ways to get this done and just working. The entire application will be compiled code, with only simple tags being viewable in aspx pages. Also, everything is intended to be very modular in nature i.e. this simple login form will serve two sides of the application that authenticate to different portions of the application's database.

Comment: could it be because Default is not inheriting from ` System.Web.UI.Page`? what does customerManagerPage do

Comment: No, CustomerManagerPage is a class that inherits from Page, so by extension Default does inherit from Page. All pages of the application inherit from this class because there is some processing that needs to happen on every page. That part of the app is working just fine, there are already existing pages of the application that inherit form this and function just fine.

Comment: ok I see now try creating your button inside of  if (IsPostBack) { }

Comment: Doing that will defeat the purpose of what I am trying to do... The entire contents of the login form (boxes, buttons, etc) are (and need to be) already created in the control code. The only thing that needs to happen at the page level is the Command event of the button created inside of the control needs to be assigned to fire a method that is declared at the page level. I'm really thinking that the binding of the Command event to the button is not happening at the appropriate place in the page's lifecycle. So, I am looking for some answers that might elaborate more on that aspect of it.

Comment: Yes I agree, maybe you should be done with it before the load event